# New tag conflicting with another tag ([re-base] and [rebase])

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation, tag-creation-process

I'm trying to create a new tag... but...

[image]

[re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) is related to another topic; it is a JavaScript library that has **1.6k stars** in GitHub with more than **5.6k downloads** last month. The problem is I can't create a new tag because it is conflicting with another one.

- [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) => A Relay inspired library for building React.js + Firebase applications.
- [rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rebase/info) => An operation in a version control system or a special way of creating a shared library

Comment: I'm not understanding the downvotes here. Yeah, someone had the bright idea to create a library and dub it "re-base", and yeah, the OP here could have put a bit more effort into their question; but I don't see how that makes this question any less appropriate. I'm not sold on the proposed outcome, but a discussion is warranted. Upvoted not for agreement, but because this question warrants exposure.

Comment: I can't understand the downvotes.. re-base library have 1.6k stars in github with more than 5.6k downloads last month on npm and I can't create a new Tag because is conflicting with another tag.    I think it's worth the discussion

Comment: The point about the library having 1.6k stars and 5.6k downloads last month should be part of the question. The rest of your comment just echoes my comment. Be careful when editing your question to not address the downvotes, because that would likely just further detract from the discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I put more explanation about the difference between two tags.

Comment: @ridermansb: It's not clear if you're trying to create the library Rebase tag or the VCS concept Rebase tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The concept of rebasing in VCSs is a critical tool. It deserves a tag more than some random JavaScript library.

So you're going to have to come up with a different name for it. Maybe [re-base-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/re-base-library), [re-base-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/re-base-js), or something similar.

This is hardly the first time such conflicts have come up. [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm) is for General Linearized Mathematics, but "GLM" is also a popular vector math library. Its tag is [glm-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm-math), but unfortunately a lot of people just use [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glm). We try to correct them whenever possible.